# How to login to a particular website given username and password in django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, iframe

I am creating a web project that involves the task of logging into a particular website. The website is loaded in an iframe. The username and password are both provided. I am using Django as the backend framework. How do you use Django (plus Javascript?) to automatically log into the website when the iframe is loaded (which happens when I click a particular link or button)? If this isn't possible, are there any alternatives to this?

The use of iframe is not really a strict requirement. It's just that part of the goal is to embed a webpage inside my page, and using iframe is the only approach that I currently know. The url of the inner page to be displayed (via iframe) is inputted, so the solution should work for different websites (facebook, google, etc.). You can't enter an "unreqistered" url though. Registered urls are the ones my database is aware of, and I can use their user-friendly name when inputting.

It's basically a single page that can display different sites, and if the site requires a login, it automatically logs the user in. The credentials for the url are saved to the database when the url was registered, and are used to log the user in.

Comment: Using an iframe like this is blocked by browsers, unless the iframe content is from your own site. The other site probably also have extra cross site scripting protection in place. What you are describing is very similar to a classic phishing attack, so it's blocked for good reason.

Comment: @HakenLid Can you recommend a safer approach to embedding a webpage within another page without the iframe issues?

Comment: Many sites make documentation and apis available for developers. It might be possible to achieve whatever you want to do that way.

Comment: If you want specific advice, you should ask a specific question. Which site is it? What approach have you tried? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @HakenLid I've edited the description. Please read again.

Comment: Frankly, I recommend abandoning this project. I doubt that there is any way of doing this within the terms of service of the sites you mention, and it's possibly in violation of data laws as well. And if I understand the description, your site have to save and retrieve user credentials using the database you control. That's a horrible idea from a security perspective.

Comment: Why is it a horrible idea?

Comment: Because it can be used for identity theft. Even if your intetions are perfectly harmless, someone else might gain access to your server or your database and use it to steal peoples emails, facebook pages etc.